# Buffer around shoreline hitting user memory limits

Tags: google-earth-engine, buffer

I am having issues hitting user memory limits creating a buffer around a shoreline. I think its because there are too many elements in the feature collection. This might be a tiling issue? How do I create a polygon or set of polygons that represent this buffer around this shoreline feature? Here is the code and asset shared:

```
var shoreline = ee.FeatureCollection("users/nateme16/eeshore");
Map.addLayer(shoreline)

var shoreline2=shoreline.geometry()
var buffer= shoreline2.buffer(200)

Map.addLayer(buffer)
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6809997e4408bb3dc19a3d5d9062dc55)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to include the relevant block of code (links aren't a valid substitute for code here).

Comment: That will need exporting. Does [this](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b959ede5f39fa6c90d478571be0d78d) work? Otherwise try exporting multiple limited featureCollections and merge them together afterwards.

Comment: Kuik, trying the export option now. thank you for also showing how to get it in the format for the export. Ill let you know if it works.

Comment: Better, but still cant do much space. I may have to break it up by state or something for the export